# AWS Console CodePipeline - Packed Policy too Large Error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been using AWS CodePipeline from within the AWS Console for years to deploy my website.  The app consists of a 4 containers.  A few weeks ago, the pipeline deploy step stopped working with this error in the console.

```
Packed policy too large! The policy constructed for the action exceeds IAM policy size limits.
Try using shorter resource names for the resources defined in this action.
```

[image]

The deploy step uses ECS Blue/Green deployment.

I haven't made any changes that I can think of that triggers this. If I remove one of the containers (doesn't matter which one) then it completes as expected.  I had this issue a couple of years prior where I was forced to consolidate and get rid of one of my containers to compensate for this, and it's happened again.  All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For whatever reason your suddenly hitting hard limits in IAM. The policy in question is probably related to STS / assume role - if so that policy is the sum of policies you control, and some that AWS would control. Take a look at the code deploy/pipeline roles in IAM. If they have inline policies defined move them to managed policies, if you have crazy long names make them shorter, consider simplifying the policies if possible etc - whatever you can do to shrink down the total policies of your role. Removing a container probably had a similar effect of reducing the policy size.

Comment: How can I tell in the AWS console if a role is managed or inline? I thought I was using managed policies but maybe I am incorrect in that.  Also, switching out from ECS Blue/Green to regular ECS got around the problem as well. not sure if that is just luck or a long term solution.

Comment: When looking at a role in IAM console with the list of policies, its the type column of policy list to look at. I think if they are AWS or Customer Managed those are as small as you can make them (ie just the ARN to the policies), any "Inline" type policies should be moved out of the role and into separate policies and then linked from the role (appearing as "Customer Managed" type in policy list).

Comment: I think downgrading from b/g or removing containers as you mentioned will fix the issue but really this is only working by making the policy smaller from removing some resources which isnt a great fix. I suspect there is a different approach somewhere in your pipeline or IAM setup to avoid this issue. Do you use different roles for builds and deploy or 1 role for everything?